# Firestore withConverter Returning Error for fromFirestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a project using Firebase Firestore and using the custom object code provided by Firebase. I am using a converter in a could trigger function and receiving an error that states fromFirestore is not a function. I am do not understand why. I've added the City class file, the cloud trigger function, and the error message found in the logs. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

City Class

```
class City {
  constructor(name, state, country) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
    this.country = country;
  }
  toString() {
    return this.name + ', ' + this.state + ', ' + this.country;
  }
}

// Firestore data converter
var cityConverter = {
  toFirestore: function (city) {
    return {
      name: city.name,
      state: city.state,
      country: city.country,
    };
  },
  fromFirestore: function (snapshot, options) {
    const data = snapshot.data(options);
    return new City(data.name, data.state, data.country);
  },
};

// Exports
module.exports = {
  City: City,
};

module.exports.cityConverter = cityConverter;
```

Cloud Trigger Function

```
exports.cityUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document('cities/{cityId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const data = change.after.data();
    const doc = change.after;

    const cityDoc = await db
      .collection('cities')
      .doc('LV')
      .withConverter(cityConverter)
      .get();

    if (cityDoc.exists) {
      const city = cityDoc.data();
      console.log(city);
      console.log(city.name);
    } else {
      console.log('No listing exists');
    }
  });
```

Error Log

> TypeError: this.ref._converter.fromFirestore is not a function
> at QueryDocumentSnapshot.data (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/document.js:311:40)
> at QueryDocumentSnapshot.data (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/document.js:488:28)
> at exports.cityUpdate.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/workspace/functions/cities.js:28:28)
> at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Firebase Admin SDK does not allow the use of withConverter and the toFirebase and fromFirebase functions. These are reserved for the JavaScript SDK. Hopefully, these functions are added to the Admin SDK.